# PHP + jQuery .ajax: POST

Tags: php, jquery

i am working on PHP and jQuery trying to do a post with jquery. It seems to work in FF but IE is giving me several error:

The follwing is the code i am using:

```
<script>
$(function()
{
$("#mainForm").submit(function()
{
dataString = $("#mainForm").serialize();
$.ajax({
type : "POST",
url : "/gops/views/groups//ajax.php",
data : dataString,
//dataType : "json",
success : function(data) {
gid = $("#group_id").val();
$('#load_skills').load('/gops/views/groups/get_skills.php?gid='+gid);
}
});
return false;
});///close submit
});//close function
</script>
```

These are the errors i am getting in IE8:
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; BRI/2; InfoPath.2)
Timestamp: Thu, 19 Jul 2012 14:11:45 UTC

Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 3
Char: 13
Code: 0

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; BRI/2; InfoPath.2)
Timestamp: Thu, 19 Jul 2012 14:12:04 UTC

Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 3
Char: 13
Code: 0
URI:

Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 2
Char: 9
Code: 0
URI:

Message: Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101.
Line: 2
Char: 11321
Code: 0
URI: =1342707101099">http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js?=1342707101099

Comment: Well the issue appears to solely be the fact you're using IE.

Comment: Unless you mean dataString to be global, define the variable as 'var dataString'.  From the error code, it seems to not be finding your mainForm element.  A little html snippet could help.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but why are you doing two ajax calls? You can just return the right data with the first one.

Comment: One other thing of note, if the code that is copy and pasted in above is verbatim.  You might want to consider the placement of the opening curly brace for the function call.  Javascript likes to terminate each line with a semi-colon if one isn't present, so it may be interpreting the function definition wrong.  Thus, try making your anonymous function call in the following format:   '$(function() {'  The same for the '$("#mainForm").submit(function()'

Answer (score 2):

well, try to execute $.noConflict() after jquery load